# Document scanning software

Tags: windows, windows-7, networking, scanning

Are there good, free, preferably FOSS document scanning software for Windows 7+ with *network* support?

HP's printer/scanner software recently stopped working due to a dependency on Flash. With Flash deprecated, HP also left the printer/scanner support high and dry: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02463264

Most of the alternatives they suggest don't work for networked printer/scanner devices. https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01796879

On Linux I'm happy with [XSane](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/XSane) and [Gnome's simple Document Scanner](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/simple-scan).

Is there something similar for Windows?

Comment: I added what I hope is the correct link for XSane.  Is it correct?  In doing so, I noticed the site indicates a Windows version.  I've never tried it though.  Would that help?

Comment: The website for Sane is http://www.sane-project.org/ and XSane is a front-end for it but its old site http://www.xsane.org/ now redirects to  https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/XSane/. Installing on linux is easy as it is available through most distros' package manager. I read it was possible to get it working on Windows but it was complicated, requiring cigwin, etc. I have no idea about the site you linked.

Comment: Thank you!  I will update the link to what you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I can highly recommend NAPS2.  It is completely open-source, and is available here:

Main page:
https://www.naps2.com/

GitHub:
https://github.com/cyanfish/naps2

SourceForge:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/naps2/

In my experience, NAPS2 works very well.  The quality of the output is excellent.  The OCR works great too.

It works wonderfully with networked devices, and does not require Flash.

The software is available as portable software, or with an installer (whichever you prefer).

The only downside to it is that a new version has not been released for about 2 years (as of 2021 January), and there are currently 9 pull requests that have not been integrated.  Hopefully, development will continue.  That said, I have not encountered any significant issues.

Comment: NAPS2 looks promising but it fails to detect the networked device when clicking the "Choose device" button with both the WIA and TWAIN drivers. I can access the printer/scanner at its local IP, so I know it is available. Is there something that needs to be done for NAPS2 to see the device?

Comment: @adatum I think you're seeing the same thing I'm seeing, but are getting a different result.  When I click the 'Profiles' button in NAPS2, a window appears.  Then, I click the 'New' button, which brings up a dialog box.  In that dialog box, there are the WIA and TWAIN buttons.  If I then select 'WIA' and press 'Choose device', I'll see the WIA network scanners.  If I select 'TWAIN' and press 'Choose device', I'll see the TWAIN network scanners.  If you're not getting the same results, perhaps try hardcoding the IP addresses for the scanners instead of using DHCP.

Comment: How do I know if the network scanner (HP L7700 all-in-one) is using WIA, TWAIN, or neither? The device is assigned a static IP by the DHCP based on its MAC, but I don't see anywhere to enter it in NAPS2's Profiles window. The "Choose device" field is not editable.

Comment: I am not sure.  In my experience (which is not unlimited!), HP all-in-one (AIO) devices typically use WIA.  Can you scan or print from other applications?  Can you assign a static IP directly on the AIO device without having to use DHCP to create the static IP assignment (don't let DHCP use that IP though!)?  Yes, the 'Device' field is not editable for me either... it wants to get a value from the 'Choose device' button. To set up the HP AIO, did you run the massive HP installer package and install its network drivers? I know HP also has/had a free download called the 'HP Print & Scan Doctor'.

Comment: To be clear, the device is not being shared via a Windows computer. It is simply assigned a static (reserved) IP on the network by the router's DHCP. Other computers can see it and add it as a network printer/scanner, at least on linux. Is it possible to access a network device directly with NAPS2, or does WIA/TWAIN require installing drivers on a Windows machine then sharing that device on the network via Windows?

Comment: @adatum I'm not 100% sure, but I found some info on the HP L7780, which should be similar to the L7700.  I think you can assign a static IP directly via the device, outside of your router's DHCP range.  Frankly, it shouldn't matter, but it can't hurt for troubleshooting purposes.  Either way, the L7700 should be available to all devices on the network (with appropriate permissions, etc.).  For NAPS2 to see it on a Windows box, either WIA or TWAIN drivers will likely need to be installed.  But that's just for the Windows box, and shouldn't affect how other devices see the L7700.

Comment: You'll also have to ensure that your firewall is not blocking the IP address of the L7700 or any of the ports required (from the Windows device).  Also, your firewall will have to be configured to allow the L7700 to communicate with the Windows device.

Comment: Where do I get the WIA or TWAIN drivers? Is that required? I don't think I installed them if they are separate from the driver software bundle provided by HP, and I don't see standalone WIA/TWAIN drivers on HP's site. Btw, the specific device model is the L7780 in the L7700 series.

Comment: @adatum The drivers should be included with the bundle included with the device, or included with Windows.  I have used similar HP AIO devices with a very similar setup, and as far as I recall, all I installed was Windows 7, the HP bundle (which *is* a hot mess), and NAPS2.  I did have to ensure the firewall and router were configured properly to allow the required packets to flow between the Windows box and the HP AIO device.

Comment: What is the proper firewall or router configuration? I tried temporarily disabling Windows Firewall but it did not help.

Comment: @adatum Since you temporarily disabled the Windows Firewall, then I would expect all traffic to be allowed during that test period.  You can likely perform the same test on your router to perform both tests simultaneously.  For security purposes, I recommend disconnecting any cables leading to the internet.

Comment: I tried with a different Windows 7 computer (instead of a Virtualbox Windows 7 virtual machine which may have network complications) and this time the device's IP is recognized (seen in screenshot) though NAPS2 always crashes within seconds of launching it. I've included the Windows event logs too: https://imgur.com/a/uh27DVT